# How to extract an indiscernible sequence from a set in a stable theory?

Tags: model-theory

I was reading Chernikov's notes about stable theories, and he mentions the following fact:

If $T$ is stable and $A$ is some set of parameters large enough then there is some indiscernible sequence $I \subseteq A$ such that $|I|=|A|$.

I have been trying to find a reference of the previous fact but I have not been lucky. Any comment, hint or reference is highly appreciated!

Comment: There's a proof of the $\omega$-stable case on pages 21-22 in [these notes](https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/b.vandenberg3/Onderwijs/Model%20theory%202016/morleys_theorem.pdf).

Comment: The general case is proved in Baldwin's 'Fundamentals of Stability Theory' in chapter 5.

Comment: @StableStudent, I couldn't find such a statement in Chernikov's notes. Can you please provide a reference where it appears?

Comment: Following up on James Hanson's comment: Specifically it is Theorem V.1.28 on p. 125 of Baldwin's book.

Comment: @LevonHaykazyan I think StableStudent is referring to the last sentence of Remark 2.34.(1) on p.18 of Chernikov's *Lecture Notes on Stability Theory*.

Comment: @AlexKruckman thanks for the reference!